# How to configure logs/catalina.out of tomcat 6 for per-app. (Configure web-app specific log file for sys.out, sys.err)

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, stdout

Requirement is this ...

We have our 3 web-applications deployed in RHEL-5 server, we deployed apps with tomcat 6.0.16.
We want to configure stdout, stderr, which are coming in tomcat/logs/catalina.out in app specific log file like,

tomcat/logs/app1.log
tomcat/logs/app2.log
tomcat/logs/app3.log

we are using log4j, but it is only generating logging details we need stdout per-app which is coming in tomcat/logs/catalina.out

Any Help Appreciated ...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this,

1. Each application must use its own log4j. You can achieve this by placing log4j.jar in WEB-INF/lib of each application.
2. In each log4j's configuration file (default location is WEB-INF/classes), specify the log file name, e.g. `log4j.appender.AppLog.File=${catalina.home}/logs/app1.log`.
3. Add `swallowOutput="true"` for each context so stdout, stderr will go to your own log.

We do this on Tomcat 5.5 but I think it should work on 6.0 also.

EDIT: Here is our META-INF/context.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context override="true" swallowOutput="true" useNaming="false">
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Thanks friend ... I want to know exactly where i have to put swallowOutput="true", is it /tomcat/conf/Catalina/www.app.com/context.xml and in which tag i have to put swallowOutput="true" ?

Comment: I edited the answer and added our context.xml. This one is better place than the one you mentioned because it doesn't depend on the container configuration.

Comment: If I am putting given context.xml than database connection is not working ... what can be problem ? we are not getting db connection from context.xml ...

Comment: If you use JNDI resource to define your datasource, you need to enable naming. Remove useNaming="false".

Comment: This post helps me and my headache is gone now... I am writing this comment on in april,2013 and this thread of 2009... so, is there any any updation? or any new way to do same?? My requirement is same mentioned by Garudadwajan....   I have already voted up for the question,answer and answers mentioned in comment by ZZ Coder

Comment: @MananShah I have same requirement here, what did you find ?