# Why file is named catalina.out?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

in contrast to other logs file

```
catalina.out
```

has different extension.
I have check logging.properties and found nothing about .out. Why and where this is set?
Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Catalina.out simply contains everything that is written to Tomcat's "System.out" and "System.err".

The name "catalina.out" comes from the catalina.sh script that is conventionally used to launch Tomcat.  If you want to change the name ... or do something funky with your out/err streams ... you can hack the script, or replace it with an alternative launch script.

The origin of the name "Catalina" is explained [here](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-catalina#name).

---

> I have check logging.properties and found nothing about .out.

The redirection of the standard output / error streams to catalina.out happens in the `catalina.sh` script.

Comment: Too to this the catalina.out if I recall only exist in a linux installation of tomcat and can be used with the tail command to see in real time the output of the server's java console

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to do it through your own log4j configuration and the swallowOutput property.
See [wiki FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q6). See also some details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332691/how-to-configure-logs-catalina-out-of-tomcat-6-for-per-app-configure-web-app-s/1338524#1338524).

log4j is just a logging package so if you're not using it, consult you're logging package's javadoc. If you're not using any logging package - you'd better start using.