# How to redirect Tomcat system.out and system.err to a file, if it starts as service?

Tags: java, tomcat, centos

I need to redirect any Tomcat output to a file, I saw some people suggesting add some command line parameters, but I starting it not with command line. Tomcat installed on CentOS and I configured it to launch on system startup (using `systemctl enable tomcat`). I can launch tomcat manually, but there is no startup.sh or catalina.sh scripts (`/bin` folder contains only `bootstrap.jar`, `catalina-tasks.xml`, `tomcat-juli.jar`) and `find / -name catalina.sh` returns nothing.

Comment: [Tomcat logging](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) explains how Tomcat can be configured to write output to files. Did you already tried that?

Comment: @uniknow yes, but it's only point up that by default tomcat write output in console and in the file. It also mentions that it is done via startup scripts, there is no startup scripts in my installation.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you further [How to configure logs/catalina.out of tomcat 6 for per-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332691/how-to-configure-logs-catalina-out-of-tomcat-6-for-per-app-configure-web-app-s)